# Can not move image files

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I use that method for moving files to another folder in Google Drive. But i can move only html files with that method. How can i fix that?

```
function moveFile(parentId, fileId) {
        var body = {'id': fileId};
        body.parents = [{'id': parentId}];

        var request = gapi.client.request({
            'path': 'drive/v2/files/' + fileId,
            'method': 'PUT',
            'body': body
        });
        request.execute(function (resp) {

        });
    }
```

Comment: Did you receive any error message? What is the actual result? Read thru the [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder#moving_files_between_folders), it might help you.

Comment: @ d.datul1990 I made a application with my client id and if i login with another google acount i can open my application and html files, but can not open or move image files. It gives error 403 ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After i added some another scopes, it works.

```
var scopes = ['profile', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file' , 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata'
        , 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts'];
```